# VAT not calculating correctly in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

**UPDATE** I have turned Option Strict ON as suggested in the comments and fixed the errors, however the VAT is still not calculating correctly, here is a GIST link to the full function

I have a problem with the VAT rate not calculating correctly,

the MOT line should always be set at 0% and the BOMOT line should set based on the customers VAT code (this customer has the standard 20% VAT code and as you can see it is set correctly [image: VAT Set Correctly]

when i change the customer to my 0 rated VAT customer the code again calculates correctly,
[image: 0 Rated customer set correctly]

now when i change the customer back from this to a Standard VAT customer it recalculates incorrect and changes the MOT line to 20% when it should be zero

[image: VAT Incorrect]

Here is the code that calculates the VAT

```
Dim FPVATCode As String = 1
                       Dim FPVATRate As Decimal = 0

                        If c.LoadCode("V", FPVATCode, "") Then
                            FPVATRate = Val(c.Rec!a2)
                        End If

                        If customerVATRate <> -1 Then
                            If customerVATRate < FPVATRate Then
                                line.VCode = customerVATCode
                            Else
                                line.VCode = FPVATCode
                            End If
                        Else
                            line.VCode = FPVATCode
                        End If
```

**THE FULL FUNCTION** [Link to full function](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3f2735efaa24a95f7830)

```
Public Sub RecalculateDocumentPrices(ByVal NewCust As String) 'V749910 (163.18)

        Dim newCustomer As New customer
        newCustomer.LoadNewCustomer(NewCust)

        ' Get the customer VAT rate
        Dim customerVATCode As String = newCustomer.GetVCode
        Dim customerVATRate As Decimal = -1
        Dim bAutoPartLinked As Boolean = Settings.AutoPartLinked

        Dim c As New Codes
        If c.LoadCode("V", customerVATCode, "") Then
            customerVATRate = Val(c.Rec!a2)
        End If

        'L762946 (163.34) - only attempt recalculation if there are some lines on the document
        If Not lines Is Nothing Then
            For Each line As Line In lines

                line.disc = 0

                Select Case line.LineType
                    Case line.lineTypes.P, line.lineTypes.LT, line.lineTypes.SS, line.lineTypes.TA

                        'for a regular (ie. Non Branch Stock) product, get the price
                        If line.DescKey2 Is Nothing OrElse line.DescKey2.ToLower <> "branch" Then

                            ''get the product price
                            Dim p As New Product
                            If p.LoadProduct(line.Part, , newCustomer.Rec!Cdisc, NewCust) Then 'V772656 (163.65) - pass the selling level of the new customer

                                'V749910 (163.19) - use the lower of the customer & product VAT rates
                                Dim productVATCode As String = p.Rec!Vcode
                                Dim productVATRate As Decimal = 0

                                If c.LoadCode("V", productVATCode, "") Then
                                    productVATRate = Val(c.Rec!a2)
                                End If

                                If customerVATRate <> -1 Then
                                    If customerVATRate < productVATRate Then
                                        line.VCode = customerVATCode
                                    Else
                                        line.VCode = p.Rec!vcode
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    line.VCode = p.Rec!vcode
                                End If

                                'Remove VatIncCheck - V838410 (1.0.164.5)
                                'set the VatInclusive price if appropriate
                                'If newCustomer.IsVATInclusiveCustomer Then

                                '    'For a non linked system, add the VAT to the price
                                '    Dim sellPrice As Decimal = p.sMSell

                                '    If Not Settings.AutoPartLinked Then
                                '        sellPrice *= Math.Round((1 + (line.vatRate / 100)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                                '    End If

                                '    line.IsVATInclusivePrice = True
                                '    line.VatInclusivePrice = sellPrice

                                'Else
                                'V772656 (163.65) - was setting the unit price THEN the VAT Inc price THEN setting IsVatInclusivePrice to false. Therefore 
                                'the unit price was being overwritten.
                                line.IsVATInclusivePrice = False
                                line.VatInclusivePrice = 0

                                If bAutoPartLinked Then 'L811755 (1.0.163.105)
                                    line.unit = p.sMSell
                                End If
                                'End If

                                'Apply markon
                                CalcMarkon(line)

                            End If

                        Else
                            'for a Branch Stock product, perform a supplier enquiry to obtain the price

                            Dim awdTmp As New AutoworkDocument
                            Dim l As New Line

                            l.Part = line.Part

                            awdTmp.LookupLine(l)

                            'V749910 (163.19) - use the lower of the customer & product VAT rates
                            Dim productVATCode As Integer = 1
                            Dim productVATRate As Decimal = 0

                            If c.LoadCode("V", productVATCode, "") Then
                                productVATRate = Val(c.Rec!a2)
                            End If

                            If customerVATRate <> -1 Then
                                If customerVATRate < productVATRate Then
                                    line.VCode = customerVATCode
                                Else
                                    line.VCode = productVATCode
                                End If
                            Else
                                line.VCode = productVATCode
                            End If

                            'set the VatInclusive price if appropriate
                            If newCustomer.IsVATInclusiveCustomer Then

                                'Branch stock not available to Linked mode so just apply the vat
                                line.IsVATInclusivePrice = True
                                line.VatInclusivePrice = Math.Round(l.unit * (1 + (line.vatRate / 100)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

                            Else
                                'V772656 (163.65) - was setting the unit price THEN the VAT Inc price THEN setting IsVatInclusivePrice to false. Therefore 
                                'the unit price was being overwritten.
                                line.IsVATInclusivePrice = False
                                line.VatInclusivePrice = 0
                                line.unit = l.unit
                            End If

                            'Apply markon
                            CalcMarkon(line)

                        End If

                    Case line.lineTypes.FPP 'L829840 (1.0.163.123)
                    Case line.lineTypes.L  'V831093 (1.0.163.123)
                        'set the VatInclusive price if appropriate
                        If newCustomer.IsVATInclusiveCustomer Then 'V831093 (1.0.163.125)

                            'Branch stock not available to Linked mode so just apply the vat
                            line.IsVATInclusivePrice = True
                            line.VatInclusivePrice = Math.Round(line.unit * (1 + (line.vatRate / 100)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

                        Else
                            'V772656 (163.65) - was setting the unit price THEN the VAT Inc price THEN setting IsVatInclusivePrice to false. Therefore 
                            'the unit price was being overwritten.
                            line.IsVATInclusivePrice = False
                            line.VatInclusivePrice = 0
                            line.unit = line.unit
                        End If

                    Case line.lineTypes.FP
                        'get the selling price of the fixed price job
                        Dim cj As New CustomJobs
                        Dim ds As DataSet
                        Dim dv As DataView


                        ds = cj.LoadCustomJob(line.Part)

                        dv = ds.Tables("CustomJob").DefaultView

                        Dim dvHead As DataView = ds.Tables("JobHeader").DefaultView

                        If dvHead.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then ''00518984 (1.0.163.105) 

                            line.cost = CType(dvHead.Table.Rows(0)("FpCost"), Decimal)

                            'V749910 (163.19) - use the lower of the customer & product VAT rates


                            'V749910 (163.18) - If a VATInclusive line, set the VATInclusive price 
                            If newCustomer.IsVATInclusiveCustomer Then
                                line.IsVATInclusivePrice = True
                                line.VatInclusivePrice = Math.Round(dvHead.Table.Rows(0)("FpSell") * (1 + (line.vatRate / 100)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                            Else
                                'V772656 (163.65) - was setting the unit price THEN the VAT Inc price THEN setting IsVatInclusivePrice to false. Therefore 
                                'the unit price was being overwritten.
                                line.IsVATInclusivePrice = False
                                line.VatInclusivePrice = 0
                                line.unit = CType(dvHead.Table.Rows(0)("FpSell"), Decimal)
                            End If
                        End If ''00518984 END

                        Dim FPVATCode As String = CType(1, String)
                        Dim FPVATRate As Decimal = 0

                        If c.LoadCode("V", FPVATCode, "") Then
                            FPVATRate = CType(Val(c.Rec!a2), Decimal)
                        End If

                        If customerVATRate <> -1 Then
                            If customerVATRate < FPVATRate Then
                                line.VCode = CType(customerVATCode, Short)
                            Else
                                line.VCode = CType(FPVATCode, Short)
                            End If
                        Else
                            line.VCode = CType(FPVATCode, Short)
                        End If

                    Case line.lineTypes.CON
                        'just set the ISVatInclusive flag on this line. The consumables amount is calculated once all lines have been processed by the SaveSess().
                        line.VCode = customerVATCode
                        line.IsVATInclusivePrice = newCustomer.IsVATInclusiveCustomer
                End Select
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VBA code written for Excel? It's hard to understand from the code you posted what the context is for your question or what some of your variables seem to signify.

Comment: Hi, No not VBA code for excel its code for a .NET Forms Web App

Comment: You should set Option Strict to ON. 'Dim FPVATCode As String = 1' is a real good start for later happening problems

Comment: @DavidSdot Thanks, when i set option strict to ON it breaks a hell lot of code i did not write so would prefer not to do that, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Corbo152 Turn Option Strict On, bite the bullet and fix at least the file you're currently working on.

Comment: @sloth Thanks, but its not my project and have therefore been told i cannot do that and must find another fix

Comment: Main Problem is you are comparing Decimals, Doubles and Strings with each other and the other way round. You can only try to convert all vars in the current code to one Type as with the current code you are comparing apples to oranges

Comment: **UPDATE** Option strict turned on and errors fixed, however VAT still not calculating correctly, @DavidSdot. i have also posted a link to a GIST with the full function that recalculates prices

Comment: All relevant code must be posted on SO. If you want to also provide a link to your code somewhere else, that's fine. But it must be here in order to have a complete question.

Comment: @mason Thanks, the only reason i didn't post all that code here is its a very long function but okay will do

Comment: full function code now added

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with your IDE line by line to make sure it's working as expected?

Comment: Yes i have and it all seems to be working as it should, its just the calculation from a 0% VAT customer to a standard 20%, backward calculation works fine, i suspect this block is the cause

Comment: ` If customerVATRate <> -1 Then
       If customerVATRate < FPVATRate Then
          line.VCode = CType(customerVATCode, Short)
     Else
       line.VCode = CType(FPVATCode, Short)
     End If
     Else
       line.VCode = CType(FPVATCode, Short)
     End If `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now resolved, VAT was being calculated from products in the wrong table,

inserted this conditional in the method and it fixed it,

```
 '00518984 Calculates VAT for items in the labour table
                        Dim lB As New Product
                        Dim dv1 As DataView = lB.LabourSearch(line.Part)
                        If dv1.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                            Dim dr1 As DataRow = dv1.ToTable.Rows(0)
                            Dim PVCode As Integer = dr1("VCode")

                            Beep()

                            line.VCode = PVCode

                        Else

                            Dim FPVATCode As String = CType(1, String)
                            Dim FPVATRate As Decimal = 0

                            If c.LoadCode("V", FPVATCode, "") Then
                                FPVATRate = CType(Val(c.Rec!a2), Decimal)
                            End If

                            line.VCode = customerVATCode

                        End If

                        '00518984 END
```